# Calling CUDA API functions from Rcpp package causes segfault

Tags: c++, r, cuda, rcpp

I am currently trying to build an R-Package which works with CUDA.
While the traditional method of creating the package would work, much like the [gputools](https://github.com/nullsatz/gputools) package, I wanted to try [Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org/) for the package as it seems more clean and convenient concerning return values.

The package installation works well so far, but the issue is that the **first call of a CUDA API function** (like `cudaMalloc()` for example) crashes my RStudio.

I created a [minimal example](https://github.com/shorschig/Rcpp-CUDA-TestPackage) to illustrate my case.

It is as simple as

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "cudaTest.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix cudaTest()
{
  testMalloc();
}
```

and

```
#include <cudaTest.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <cuda.h>

void testMalloc()
{
  size_t
    fbytes = sizeof(double);
  double
    *d_mat;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_mat, 200*50*fbytes);
    cudaFree(d_mat);
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Is the integration supported this way?

EDIT:
Installing the package on the command line (`R CMD INSTALL`) and executing it in the R REPL actually gives me the error, which is a common segfault.

[image: Segfault after executing example]

Comment: You could look into other packages using Rcpp and CUDA; maybe [gpuR](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/gpuR/index.html) helps.  I also find the ArrayFire abstraction helpful, see [this Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/introducing-rcpparrayfire/).

Comment: I thought I'd take a look at your project on github, but it doesn't build. It requires external system libraries. Might be worth adding a README on which ones & how to install them.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I tried to create a README with dependencies, hoping it will suffice. As everything is already set up on my machine, it's quite hard to test if anything is missing.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for your input, but gpuR does not use CUDA but OpenCL for GPU access. Also, the goal of this project was to stay pretty close to CUDA itself for benchmarking purposes.

Comment: this [blog](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/accelerate-r-applications-cuda/) may be of interest

Comment: Can you run it with `gdb` to see where the segfault happens? BTW, you should probably use `void cudaTest()` since the function does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @RalfStubner, the mistake generating the error above was indeed just the declaration of a return type that was never returned.

So instead of

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix cudaTest()
{
  testMalloc();
}
```

it should rather be

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void cudaTest()
{
  testMalloc();
}
```

(While this was a rather simple problem, on my original pretty large project the error was the same with a different setup. I thought the `cudaMalloc` was the problem because I was only able to debug my way through with `printf` statements, which were completely omitted when the erroneous part was introduced. In this larger project, the error was a wrapper around the launch of CUDA kernels, which was simply removed afterwards.)